# passing data from a child activity to main activity

Tags: android

i have two activities main Activity and activity two ,
basically i am trying to pass a text from activity two to main activity when i click the button in main activity 
but its always retrieve null
any help why it doesn't send back the message

that is main activity code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Recieve =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMessage();
            }

        });
    }

    public void sendMessage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("Key");
            Recieve.setText(requiredValue);

        }
    }
```

And that is Activity2 code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        send();

    }
    public void send(){
        String message ="hello";
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("key", message);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `send()`, you use `"key"` with a lowercase `k`.

In `onActivityResult()`, you use `"Key"` with a capital `K`.

These do not match, which is why you are not getting your response.

Perhaps you should define your key in one place, as a constant (`final static`), and use the same constant definition in both activities.

Comment: The static final String used as a key must be public in order to be used into multiple class (activities). I'd also add that it is better to set it in the activity receiving the data (MainActivity here), so other activities could use it consistently without having to load a thrid-party activity to give the response.

Comment: @Feuby: "must be public in order to be used into multiple class" -- only if they are different Java packages. Otherwise, package private will suffice.